# How do I check whether a file or file directory exist in bash?

Tags: bash, if-statement

I currently have this bash script (which is located in my home directory, i.e., `/home/username/` and I am running it as root as it's necessary for the icon copying lines):

```
cd /home/username/Pictures/Icon*

declare -a A={Arch,Debian,Fedora,Mageia,Manjaro,OpenSUSE}
declare -a B={Adwaita,Faenza,gnome,Humanity}

for i in $A; do
  for j in $B; do
    if test -e /usr/share/icons/$j/scalable ; else
        mkdir /usr/share/icons/$j/scalable/
    fi
    if test -e /usr/share/icons/$j/scalable/$i.svg ; else
      cp -a $i*.svg /usr/share/icons/$j/scalable/$i.svg
    fi
  done
done
```

What I want this script to do is to copy icons from my `Pictures/Icons and logos` directory to the `scalable` theme (specified in `$B`) subdirectories in `/usr/share/icons`. Before it does this, however, I'd like it to create a `scalable` directory in these theme subdirectories if it does not already exist. The problem is that the else part of the conditionals is not being read properly, as I keep receiving this error:

```
./copyicon.sh: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `else'
./copyicon.sh: line 8: `    if test -e /usr/share/icons/$j/scalable ; else'
```

If you're wondering why the `test -e ...` in the conditional it's based on a textbook on bash scripting I've been following.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## Checking file and/or directory existence

To check whether a file exists in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), you use the `-f` operator. For directories, use `-d`. Example usage:

```
$ mkdir dir
$ [ -d dir ] && echo exists!
exists!
$ rmdir dir
$ [ -d dir ] && echo exists!
$ touch file
$ [ -f file ] || echo "doesn't exist..."
$ rm file
$ [ -f file ] || echo "doesn't exist..."
doesn't exist...
```

For more information simply execute `man test`.

A note on `-e`, this test operator checks whether a file exists. While this may seem like a good choice, it's better to use `-f` which will return false if the file isn't a regular file. `/dev/null` for example is a file but nor a regular file. Having the check return true is undesired in this case.

**A note on variables**

Be sure to quote variables too, once you have a space or any other special character contained in a variable it can have undesired side effects. So when you test for existence of files and directories, wrap the file/dir in double quotes. Something like `[ -f "/path/to/some/${dir}/" ]` will work while the following would fail if there is a space in `dir`: `[ -f /path/to/some/${dir}/ ]`.

## Fixing the syntax error

You are experiencing a syntax error in the control statements. A bash `if` clause is structured as following:

```
if ...; then
    ...
fi
```

Or optional with an `else` clause:

```
if ...; then
    ...
else
    ...
fi
```

You cannot omit the `then` clause. If you wish to only use the `else` clause you should negate the condition. Resulting in following code:

```
if [ ! -f "/usr/share/icons/$j/scalable" ]; then
    mkdir "/usr/share/icons/$j/scalable/"
fi
```

Here we add an exclamation point (`!`) to flip the expression's evaluation. If the expression evaluates to true, the same expression preceded by `!` will return false and the other way around.

Comment: Changing `test -e ...` to  `test [-d ...]` gives: ./copyicon.sh: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `else'
./copyicon.sh: line 8: `    if test [ -d /usr/share/icons/$j/scalable ] ; else'

Comment: That's because your syntax is wrong. I'll update the answer.

Comment: By "negate the condition" you mean the exclamation point (!) returns true if the directory doesn't exist but false if it does exist?

Comment: Exactly! The exclamation point transforms a true in a false and the other way around. - So if the expression is false, the same expression with a `!` will return true and the other way around!

Comment: How we can check *.txt files available in /home/tmp directory ??

Answer (score 9):

You can't skip the *then* part of the *if* statement, easiest solution would be to just negate the test

```
if [[ ! -e /usr/share/icons/${j}/scalable ]] ; then
    mkdir /usr/share/icons/${j}/scalable/
fi
if [[ ! -e /usr/share/icons/${j}/scalable/${i}.svg ]] ; then
  cp -a ${i}*.svg /usr/share/icons/${j}/scalable/${i}.svg
fi
```

I left it with -e (exists), but you might consider using -d for directories or -f for files and some error handling to catch stuff (e.g. */usr/share/icons/$j/scalable/* exists, but is a file and not a directory for whatever reason.)
I also noticed that in your original code you are potentially trying to copy multiple files into one:

```
cp -a $i*.svg /usr/share/icons/$j/scalable/$i.svg
```

I left it that way in my example in case you are sure that it is always only one file and are intentionally renaming it. If not I'd suggest only specifying a target directory.

Comment: This is great. For me, works for both directories OR files. :)

Comment: How we can check *.txt files available in /home/tmp directory ??